# about the structure of components of tensor product if more than one bipartite graph is taken

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, tensor-products

I was reading about ***tensor product*** of graphs. We know that if we take tensor product of *n* graphs and want this product to be a connected graph then at most one graph should be bipartite. In the book ***Handbook of Product graphs***, its written that if we have *k* number of bipartite graphs then the number of components in this product will be $2^{k-1}$. I just want to know is there any way or known result by which we can get information about the structure and type of components of tensor product of graphs when more than one bipartite graph is taken into product. Any idea or hint will be of great help. Thanks.